# create a web service client with a WSDL that is private

Tags: java, eclipse, webservice-client

I would like to create a soap web service client in java using eclipse. How do I do it if the wsdl is private?

I have tried the approach described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11iGyrvBhzc

I tried with another WSDL link (https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl) and it generates the files. so it works.

Haven't gotten to the code part. My problem is that when I try the approach with the WSDL link of my interest, it doesnt work because the WSDL link is private. Only people from my company have access to it. How do I make the connection?

Expected result is a set of files in my eclipse explorer

Comment: Can you get the wsdl files at all? Download them with a browser or have them emailed to you? Are you allowed to use that webservice? Usually getting access to the wsdl is easier than to the webservice.

Comment: yes, I have the wsdl link. So for example I tried this public link https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl and when I called that link on eclipse it generated the files that I was expecting.
Then I tried the same with the wsdl link that I'm interested in (the one that is private from my company) but it doesn't work. My guess is that the privacy thing is causing the issue

Comment: I meant can you download them to your local computer? You don't need to generate a client from a link, you can generate a client from files on the local computer.

Comment: you mean download the wsdl link to my computer? Well the approach I'm following requires me to put a URL containing the wsdl. If I download the wsdl content to my computer, that wouldn't be a URL anymore

Comment: Why do you need to follow that approach?

Comment: I am new to this. I know java the language and eclipse but not how to connect to web services so that is the approach I found. Do you know other approach that may be better/easier/more straight forward?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and had to do a thorough research.
This is what I found at [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13224_01/wlw/docs103/guide/webservices/conWsdlFiles.html).

> **Imported WSDL Files**
>
> When you want to use an external web service from within Workshop, you should first obtain
> the WSDL file for the service you want to use. For public web services, the WSDL file will
> typically be available on the web site of the organization that publishes the web service.
>
> For private web services, contact the organization that supports the web service to obtain the WSDL file.

When I contacted the organization that publishes the webservice, they gave me the following

1. Web service url
2. Web service specification which include xml request and response formats, and web service methods.

With the above information, I was able to consume the organization web service successfully.

Answer (score 0):

through a maven plugin you can generate the files pointing to your local directory as below:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mkdir</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>mkdir</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-pv</argument>
                                <argument>target/generated-sources/wsimport</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>wsdl</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>java</executable>

                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                <classpath/>
                                <argument>com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport</argument>
                                <argument>-extension</argument>
                                <argument>-Xnocompile</argument>
                                <argument>-catalog</argument>
                                <argument>/META-INF/jax-ws-catalog.xml</argument>
                                <argument>-wsdllocation</argument>
                                <argument>/META-INF/file.wsdl</argument>
                                <argument>-s</argument>
                                <argument>target/generated-sources/wsimport</argument>
                                <argument>src/main/resources/META-INF/file.wsdl</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```